# Python Variable Division

Tags: python, variables, decimal, division

I've been making a Python program where I suppose it counts how many seconds it takes for Python 2 to make 100 cycles, and I've decided to at the end convert this to Hz. This requires me to change the second count to 1, which I've decided is easiest by dividing by itself. Note time equates to end - start:

```
time / time
```

Pretty simple.
Problem is, this doesn't seem to work: the time variable remains the same. I've tried using two slashes, putting 'float' in front and surrounding the two variables, and I have from **future** import division in, but none seem to work. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Oisin

NOTE: The time variable is not an integer, and I'd rather not have it truncated. If it will be with your solution, tell me anyway, I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: `time / time` doesn't tell Python to *do* anything with the results of the division.

Comment: I don't see any assignment statement. Can you show us runnable [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What is `time`? What is expected behaviour? What is current behaviour?

Comment: `time / time` is always `1` for all integers `time`.

Comment: You want to do `1/time` not `time/time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something with `time` and define time. This will work:

```
time = 1
print time/time  #Output is 1
```

If you simply have a statement but your variables aren't defined and you don't use it in someway, nothing will happen. Division can always be performed with just the `/` as long you don something about it.

```
time/time #nothing

time/time + 1 #nothing

var = time/time  #var becomes result

print time/time #prints the result
```

Also, don't name your variable `time` as Python has a `time` module to avoid confusion. If `time` is equal to 1, then the result will always be 1. Try changing the equation to something else as `x/x` will always be 1. Try something else like `1/time` as suggested in the comments.

Comment: I think he wants to do `1/time` and not `time/time`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - have since added 'time =' to the front of 'time / time'; calculations work out. thanks again!